# jQuery Plot chart json data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqplot

I have a problem with jQuery plot chart it works fine but when I load data from php and json it doesnt work it show me nothing.

This is my result from php

```
[{"label":"Patrik","data":4},{"label":"Miroslav","data":28}]
```

And flot

```
            $.getJSON( "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/dashboard/getChartData", function( data ) {
            console.log(data);

            var options = {
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                bars: {
                    align: "center",
                    barWidth: 0.5
                },
                xaxis: {
                    ticks: data.title
                },
                legend: {
                    noColumns: 0,
                    labelBoxBorderColor: "#fff",
                    position: "nw"
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: "#cecece",
                    backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
                }
            };

            $.plot($("#chart_1_1"), [ data ], options);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The Json Data that You Receive needs to be converted to Array of arrays Format `[[key,value],[key,value]]` before you can give it to jqplot. Currently You are having array of  objects